# ServiceStack Disable HttpRequestValidation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I'm offering a simple test service, now a clients posts a payload which is considered dangerous so the httpRequestValidation failes.

I tried to deactivate the HTTPValidation like I do in MVC

```
  <pages validateRequest="false">
```

but this doesnt help.
is there something special I have to set for ServiceStack ?

Exception Details:

> System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException occurred
>   HResult=-2147467259   Message=Ein möglicherweise gefährlicher
>   Request.Form-Wert wurde vom Client (payload="... foo@mail.com...")
>   entdeckt.   Source=System.Web   ErrorCode=-2147467259   WebEventCode=0
>   StackTrace:
>          bei System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateString(String value, String collectionKey, RequestValidationSource requestCollection)
>   InnerException:

Any hints ?

Comment: Does this request contains HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ServiceStack doesn't add any request validation itself so this is likely an ASP.NET validation restriction. See this [answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client):

To disable Request validation, ensure that you have added both to Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <pages validateRequest="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```